# Error when uploading an image to Wordpress that is larger than 2048x1214px

Tags: php, wordpress, file-upload

When trying to upload images using the media uploading tool in the Wordpress admin panel, some uploads (not all) fail and Wordpress displays the following message :

```
Error: An error occurred in the upload. Please try again later.
```

What I've tested so far:

- Changed the theme (for eleven twelve)
- Disabled all plugins
- Raised to 128MB upload_max_filesize, post_max_filesize and max_execution_time to 300 in php.ini

Testing pixel by pixel, I've found out that any image larger than exactly 2048x1214px will fail to upload.

Well, actually, it doesn't fail to upload. Wordpress tells us it does, and shows us in the gallery a "missing thumbnail" icon instead of the image thumbnail. But if I look in the uploads folder via FTP, the file is there, but no thumbnails were created. For smaller files, it automatically creates 3 different thumbnails.

When debugging, I have this in the log:

```
[21-Mar-2016 14:17:31 UTC] PHP Warning:  Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by (output started at /homepages/19/d609483141/htdocs/wp-content/plugins/ajax-thumbnail-rebuild/ajax-thumbnail-rebuild.php:26) in /homepages/19/d609483141/htdocs/wp-admin/async-upload.php on line 35
[21-Mar-2016 14:17:34 UTC] PHP Deprecated:  Methods with the same name as their class will not be constructors in a future version of PHP; AjaxThumbnailRebuild has a deprecated constructor in /homepages/19/d609483141/htdocs/wp-content/plugins/ajax-thumbnail-rebuild/ajax-thumbnail-rebuild.php on line 26
```

If I disable the Ajax Thumbnail Rebuild extension, I don't get these errors anymore in the log, but it doesn't change anything to the upload issue.

So that's what we've got : **any file larger than 2048x1214px (no matter what the file size is) will upload but not convert to thumbnails, and Wordpress will say the upload failed though it appears in the Uploads folder.**

Any clue? I can't find anything... Thanks!

Comment: Did you check the content of WordPress' debug.log file after defining `WP_DEBUG_LOG` to `true` ?

Comment: I edited the post with this information. Thanks